# Get rid of double hover in plotly

Tags: r, hover, plotly, linechart

I've got a chart that shows two kinds of data and the forecast for them for further months. I use `hovermode = "x"` to get hover for two lines at the same times. And everything works but... in the part, where `amount` is equal to `forecast` the hover is doubled. It is quite logical but I would like to get rid of one of this values. Do you know how to deal with it?

[image]

My data:

```
dane <- structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
                       amount1 = c(1086L, 1027L, 1024L, 1080L, 1072L, 1144L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       amount2 = c(1057, 1067, 1068, 1060, 1056, 1040, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                       amount1_forecast = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1144L, 1119L, 1165L, 1145L, 1170L, 1158L, 1115L),
                       amount2_forecast = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1040L, 1178L, 1122L, 1145L, 1158L, 1175L, 1119L)),
                       row.names = c(NA, -12L),
                       .Names = c("month", "amount1", "amount2", "amount1_forecast", "amount2_forecast"),
                       class = "data.frame")
```

My plot:

```
library("plotly")

wyk <- plot_ly(dane, x = ~month)

wyk %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount1,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "blue"),
              line = list(color = "blue")) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount1_forecast,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "blue"),
              line = list(color = "blue", dash = "dot"),
              showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount2,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "red"),
              line = list(color = "red")) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount2_forecast,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "red"),
              line = list(color = "red", dash = "dot"),
              showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
    layout(hovermode = "x") -> wyk

wyk
```

Thanks for any idea!

PS I know, that without option `hovermode = "x"` it works but I would like to keep it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've came up with such an idea:

```
library("dplyr")

dane %>% 
    mutate(amount1_hover = ifelse(is.na(amount1_forecast), amount1, NA),
           amount2_hover = ifelse(is.na(amount2_forecast), amount2, NA)) -> dane

wyk <- plot_ly(dane, x = ~month)

wyk %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount1,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              text = dane$amount1_hover,
              hoverinfo = "text",
              marker = list(color = "blue"),
              line = list(color = "blue")) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount1_forecast,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              text = ~amount1_forecast,
              hoverinfo = "text",
              marker = list(color = "blue"),
              line = list(color = "blue", dash = "dot"),
              showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount2,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "red"),
              text = dane$amount2_hover,
              hoverinfo = "text",
              line = list(color = "red")) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~amount2_forecast,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines+markers",
              marker = list(color = "red"),
              text = ~amount2_forecast,
              hoverinfo = "text",
              line = list(color = "red", dash = "dot"),
              showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
    layout(hovermode = "x")
```

But maybe somebody knows better solution!